# urllib.request.urlopen("ftp://username:password@ftpserver/file" returns <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> if password contains '#'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

urllib.request.urlopen("ftp://username:password@ftpserver/file" returns <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known> if password contains '#'

Could someone let me know if there are any known issues? or workaround or fix available for this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` library doesn't usually like `ftp://` type links.

To download a file from an FTP server I would recommend using `urlretrieve`.

Try something like the following:

```
import urllib.request

urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://server/path/to/file', 'file')
# if you need to pass credentials try 
urllib.request.urlretrieve('ftp://username:password@server/path/to/file', 'file')
```

To get around the `#` issue, we can use URL encoding by changing to the characters `%23` which should be recognized as `#`.

Ex:`mypassword%23` will be recognized as `mypassword#`

[HTML URL ENCODING REFERENCES](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP)

Comment: This also gives the same error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1555, in ftp_open
    host = socket.gethostbyname(host)
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known


urllib.request.urlopen("ftp://username:password@ftpserver/file") works well with all other passwords (passwords with other special chars like @, +, - ,*, %, =). It fails only if the password contains '#'

Comment: @Venkat, I think I misunderstood the problem. I added to my original post

Comment: Thanks @Carter Turbett. Encoding works.